# Using HIVE UDF with hiveconf variables

Tags: java, hive, hiveql, udf

I have a Hive UDF which returns the IP range for a given IP and it looks something like this:

```
public class IPToRangeUDF extends UDF {
    ...
    ...
    public String evaluate(String ip,Integer option) throws Exception{
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Basically based on the option I am returning specific things from the range.

Now while trying to use this UDF in Hive after properly adding jar and creating function:

```
ADD JAR <jar path here>/myJAR.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ipToRange AS 'IPToRangeUDF';
```

Queries like this run without any problems. (`mytable` is an existing table that has a column `ip`(type STRING) and I am passing the `option` directly.):

```
select ip,ipToRange(ip,0) from myTable;
```

The problem comes when I try to use a hiveconf variable as the IP. Example:

```
SET IP='99.67.53.221';
select count(*) from myTable where ip>=ipToRange(${hiveconf:IP},0);
```

The query doesn't run and gives the following exception:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:56 Wrong arguments '0':
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
Unable to execute method public java.lang.String  
IPToRangeUDF.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
throws java.lang.Exception  on object IPToRangeUDF@1b8a29df of class 
IPToRangeUDF with arguments {99.67.53.221:java.lang.String, 0:java.lang.Integer} of size 2
```

Any help/advice is appreciated.